# Matching placeholders in Python

Tags: python, string, parsing, nlp

I have a set of phrases which I check against in a piece of text.

A straightforward phrase of the form 'as soon as possible' is easy to check for, like so:

```
if phrase in text:
    ...
```

I also have phrases of the form 'a {JJ} amount of' where JJ is a placeholder for any adjective. So basically, if the text contains something like 'a small amount of', then the phrase 'a {JJ} amount of' is present.

How do I match patterns of this form?

Comment: A regular expression, perhaps? `r'a \w+ amount of'`?

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not sure if that'll do. I have hundreds of phrases with similar placeholders, and I'm looking for a non-specific way of handling them.

Comment: Do you require determining if a word is an adjective? Because that is a more difficult problem.

Comment: So you have these phrases in a file somewhere in the form `'a {JJ} amount of'`? Then you can use a regex as suggested just replacing the `{JJ}` with `w+`

Comment: Ok, I just looked into generating regex dynamically and turns out your solution works perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions to accomplish. For your example, you can do something like this:

```
re.findall(r"a\s\w+?\samount of", text)
```

this will return all instances of the phrase given in your example. `\s\w+?\s` will match a single word, so you can simply modify the words around that if you need to change the pattern. You can find the pattern from your phrase outline by simply doing something like `phrase.replace("{JJ}", r"\s\w+?\s")`

Comment: Don't you mean `\b` rather than `\s`? The latter matches on whitespace, not word boundaries.

Comment: @DanielRoseman No, `\b` doesn't make sense here. For example, I wouldn't wanna match "a small. amount of." Space is really the only thing that makes sense as a word boundary in this context.

Comment: But this expression won't match "a small amount of", because now you're expecting two spaces. And `\w` only matches alphanumeric characters anyway, so wouldn't match on the ".".

Comment: \b is essentially \W. It isn't what I want. But you are correct, I had extra spaces.